# How many Bits for operand specification in indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, low-level, opcode

Hey^^ hopefully someone can help me out here:
The question in a test is the following (I had to translate it)
A CPU has 16 General Purpose Registers, it handles data and addresses with a length of 32 bit.
How many bits need to be used at least for the operand specification for the specific addressing mode:

I guess that the architecture which is used is a LOAD/STORE Architecture (was the standard in the lecture)

**indirect addressing**

so in assembly it would be something like `mov eax, [ebx]`
which represents a LOAD instruction (correct me if im wrong)

As far as I know a machine instruction consists of:

OP.C OpCode | OP.D (Destination register) |OP.1 | OP.2

OP.D and OP.1/2 are the operand specification

So for the 16 GPR´s I would need 4 Bit to address them but do I need 4 bit for the ebx register which holds the address or do I need 32 bit for the address from the beginning?

Comment: *A CPU has 16 General Purpose Registers, it handles data and addresses with a length of 32 bit* - Then your CPU isn't x86; in 32-bit mode, x86 has 8 GPRs of 32-bit width.  In 64-bit mode, it has 16 GPRs of 64-bit width (and a weird way of encoding the extra bit in the register-numbers for base/index and the reg-only operand, via a REX prefix.)  Specifying a 32-bit address-size (so [ebx] as opposed to [rbx]) also takes an extra prefix, `67h` address-size.

Comment: An load with a `[register]` addressing mode just needs a register number in the machine code.  The final address is a runtime-variable and obviously can't be embedded into the machine code by the assembler.